# How do I get the lists of list' first element in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Let's say we have a matrix, represented by a list of lists, e.g.: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

How do I write a predicate that gets
`[[1,4][4,7][2,5][5,8][3,6][6,9]]`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In the following logically-pure Prolog code I use [definite clause grammars](http://www.logic.at/prolog/dcg.html) [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg):

```
matrix_adjacentPairs([]) -->
   [].
matrix_adjacentPairs([Xs|Xss]) -->
   list_adjacentPairs(Xs),
   matrix_adjacentPairs(Xss).

list_adjacentPairs([]) -->
   [].
list_adjacentPairs([X|Xs]) -->
   list_adjacentPairs_(Xs,X).                 % use "lagging"

list_adjacentPairs_([],_) -->
   [].
list_adjacentPairs_([X1|Xs],X0) -->
   [[X0,X1]],
   list_adjacentPairs_(Xs,X1).
```

Here is the query that the OP stated:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).                % SWI-Prolog transpose/2
:- use_module(library(lists)).                % SICStus Prolog transpose/2

?- transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],Tss),
   phrase(matrix_adjacentPairs(Tss),Pss).
Tss = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]],
Pss = [[1,4],[4,7],[2,5],[5,8],[3,6],[6,9]].
```

---

#### Edit 2015-04-26

Using meta-predicates [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and [`foldadjl/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) with [library(lambda)](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), it all boils down to:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],Tss),
   phrase(foldl(foldadjl(\X^Y^[[X,Y]|Xs]^Xs^true),Tss),Pss).
Tss = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]],
Pss = [[1,4],[4,7],[2,5],[5,8],[3,6],[6,9]].
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `transpose/2` exists in SICStus Prolog, in SWI-Prolog `transpose/2` transposes a matrix, e.g.:

```
?- transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], R).
R = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]].
```

Now, here is what you can do in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

combis(L, R) :-
    transpose(L, L1),
    create_lst_combis(L1, R).

create_lst_combis([], []).   
create_lst_combis([H | T], R) :-
    create_lst_combis(T, R1),
    create_combis(H, CH),
    append(CH, R1, R).    

create_combis([H , T], [[H, T]]) :- !.  
create_combis([H | T], R) :-
    maplist(create_one_combi(H), T, T1),
    create_combis(T, R1),
    append(T1, R1, R).

create_one_combi(H, V, [H, V]).
```